# How to kill CountDownTimer When I start an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, countdowntimer

I have two activities. ActivityA has a countdowntimer. When I start ActivityB from ActivityA , timer doesn't stop. How can I do it ?

```
myTimer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) { 
    @Override public void onFinish()

     Intent mainIntent = new Intent(QRcode.this,ActivityC.class); 
     QRcode.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

}; 
myTimer.start();
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(QRcode.this,ActivityB.class); 

QRcode.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Comment: Show the code where you are declaring the timer. usually you can stop in onPause() function of the Activity A.

Comment: myTimer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
       @Override
       public void onFinish() 

       };

       myTimer.start();Intent mainIntent = new Intent(QRcode.this,BarcodeGecis.class);
   mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
           QRcode.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

Answer (score 4):

In `ActivityA` run this code before you start `ActivityB`

```
    myTimer.cancel();
    myTimer = null;
```

and reset your start time 20000. Now when this `Activity` is created again it should reset your `CountDownTimer` object.

Comment: But myTimer starts on create. And you say myTimer cancel on create. It's an error.

Comment: Why are you starting the timer then switching `Activities`? Maybe I don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: ActivityA starts timer. When Timer finishes, call ActivityC. But before the timer finishes, When I start ActivityB, timer countinue and timer finishes in ActivityB, it calls ActivityC.

Comment: Ok, and what exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: I updated my code at top. The timer runs out, when I start ActivityB , it shouldn't start ActivityC.

Comment: But you start `ActivityB` right after starting your timer so what is the purpose of your timer?

Comment: Actually, my application is complex. I want to explain simple to you.

Comment: Its good to keep it simple but I think I'm missing something important about what you are doing which makes it hard to help. If you start `ActivityB` right after setting the timer then the timer is useless. If you are doing other code while timer is started before `ActivityB` is started then in `onPause()` you could cancel the timer there in `ActivityA`